# C# & Access Database: Unrecognized database format

Tags: c#, ms-access

Built a program that reads an access database file and exports to excel what is loaded into the datagrid.

It works with a sample database I constructed but not with the actual database i'm trying to pull data from. They are both `.accdb` files.

Error Message:
[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace DataExporter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //List<Product> list = ((DataParameter)e.Argument).ProductList;
            System.Data.DataTable list = ((DataParameter)e.Argument).ProductList;
            string filename = ((DataParameter)e.Argument).FileName;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
            Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;
            excel.Visible = false;
            int index = 1;
            //int process = list.Count;
            int process = list.Rows.Count;
            //Add Column
            ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Item Number";
            ws.Cells[1, 2] = "Model";
            ws.Cells[1, 3] = "Manufacturer";
            ws.Cells[1, 4] = "Category";
            ws.Cells[1, 5] = "Subcategory";
            foreach (DataRow dr in list.Rows)
            {
                if (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(index++ * 100 / process);
                    ws.Cells[index, 1] = dr.ItemArray[1].ToString();
                    ws.Cells[index, 2] = dr.ItemArray[2].ToString();
                    ws.Cells[index, 3] = dr.ItemArray[3].ToString();
                    ws.Cells[index, 4] = dr.ItemArray[4].ToString();
                    ws.Cells[index, 5] = dr.ItemArray[5].ToString();
                }
            }
            //Save file
            ws.SaveAs(filename, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, false, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            excel.Quit();
        }

        struct DataParameter
        {
            public System.Data.DataTable ProductList;
            public string FileName { get; set; }
        }

        DataParameter _inputParameter;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Wizard_Data-2016-10-17.accdb";
            using (OleDbConnection olcon = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                {

                    string command = "SELECT * FROM [Inventory]";
                    //cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";

                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, olcon);
                    //Fill Gridview with Data from Access
                    try
                    {
                        dt.Clear();
                        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        adapter.Fill(dt);
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        olcon.Close();
                        var totalWidth = dataGridView1.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.None);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            lblStatus.Text = string.Format("Processing...{0}", e.ProgressPercentage);
            progressBar.Update();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                lblStatus.Text = "Your data has been successfully exported.";
            }
        }
        private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
                return;
            using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xls" })
            {
                if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    _inputParameter.FileName = sfd.FileName;
                    //_inputParameter.ProductList = GetProductsList2();
                    _inputParameter.ProductList = (System.Data.DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
                    progressBar.Minimum = 0;
                    progressBar.Value = 0;
                    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(_inputParameter);
                }
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** 
I saved my access database to `.mdb` format and the program does run. Something to do with `.accdb` format?

Comment: Check few things like- 1) the project type: 32/64 bit 2) version of the files and your compatible OLEDB driver 3) Target CPU You can meanwhile try setting the target CPU to 'Any CPU' and check if that works

Comment: On what line is the exception thrown and what is the connection string for the manitest.accdb file?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh in the VS Configuration Manager the Platform is already set to Any CPU

Comment: @MichaelDotKnox the error states line 84 which is `adapter.Fill(dt);`